# What's an effective threading structure for NIO and server performance in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, performance, networking

I run into this issue where if I do a read to check for data too often, my CPU skyrockets, and if I don't check often enough, it's slow for client performance. What's an effective way to deal with this & NIO?

Comment: There's plenty of material about NIO in C and C++ on the Internet.  Alas, precious little of it addresses the performance aspects.  Some of the blogs say "TODO: Write about performance here."

Comment: **[Unclear what help you need](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important).** Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your approach needs to be corrected or explained. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @gnat Robert seems to know exactly what I'm talking about. It's about the performance.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258433/839601

Comment: I found what I was looking for, the answer in POSIX(Unix/Linux/Mac(?)) systems is `poll()`. In windows, there is `WSAPoll`, however it is not efficient.

Comment: You shouldn't need to *check* for data, you should ask the OS to tell you when it's available.

Comment: @immibis That's `poll`, correct? This has been what I've been trying to figure out.

Comment: @JavaProphet I've never used `poll`, but if I'm not misunderstanding the documentation, then yes, it's a way to do that. (Crucially, you want to pass it all your sockets at once, and use a large timeout - don't loop over all the sockets and check them individually with zero timeout)

Comment: @immibis What you said not to do was exactly what I was, thank you. If you would like, you can post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to *check* for data to be received from a socket. You want to ask the OS to tell you when data is received.

With `poll` (or `select`), you can pass it a bunch of sockets at once, and a large (or infinite) timeout. `poll` will return some data's been received on any of the sockets you passed it. If nothing is received, it will keep waiting without wasting CPU time. If something is received, it will return immediately.